# Why Google Maps no longer disable Mercator's projection on zoom out

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps

Back in 2018, [Google Maps start to get rid of mercator's projection in maximum zoom-out](https://twitter.com/googlemaps/status/1025130620471656449)

So we can see the size of island (moreover those in poles) in it's original sizes

But today I try both in PC and phone, doesn't seem to work that way

Do they switch to previous decision? But why?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two settings that have to be right for the globe mode to work.

First setting is Chrome browser hardware acceleration setting:
`Settings > Advanced > System > Use hardware acceleration when available > On`

**EDIT** (December 2022):
System settings are now directly under Settings:
`Settings > System > Use hardware acceleration when available > On`

Second setting is globe mode in Google Maps:

1. Move mouse over Layers selection icon in the lower left corner:

[image]

2. Click on More:

[image]

3. Enable Globe view:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I didn't need to change anything around hardware acceleration settings (which I couldn't find in the menus) and simply enabled _Globe view_ and it worked.

Comment: @CoryKlein See modified answer.